# How can I extract 7 million records from Oracle database to CSV file

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have already tried the export option in the sql developer,it is very time consuming.
I need to know if there is quicker way to extract data to CSV file.

Comment: how long does it take to run the query? when you do the export, we run the query, AGAIN - exporting out to CSV in SQL Dev is fast...7 million(?) records might take awhile, so how long is it taking?

Comment: In the future, please don't use Indian words like "lakh" here.

Comment: I will take care of that, for 600k records it took more than an hour

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSf2u.png)

I think you can try with Toad for oracle in DataGrid view then right click and export Data Set, you can start with a million with `WHERE ROWNUM < 1000001`

Comment: Is doing that through Toad going to be faster than doing the same thing from SQL Developer?

Comment: Yeah i´d rather use Toad, is faster than developer with many data in general

Comment: with 500,000 rows it took 2.45 minutes do the math

Comment: i don't see any math

Comment: i just dumped all_source, 500k rows, to CSV in less than 20 seconds

Comment: Is it a SSD, @Jeff?

Comment: intel i5-7300U CPU, 16GB RAM, Lenovo M.2 SSD @Littlefoot

Comment: I thought it was a SSD; a *slow* HDD wouldn't store 500K rows in 20 seconds :), @Jeff.

Comment: @Littlefoot true, but don't most developers have SSD now? or really any machine sold in the last 36 months?